# How to pass array to nsuserdefaults and use them in a section in tableview

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

This is my array

```
[
    {
        "Description" : null,
        "Message" : null,
        "vmanager_account" : "True",
        "user_id" : "174",
        "login_name" : "ssrikanth",
        "user_name" : "Surya Srikanth",
        "owner_id" : "1",
        "user_email" : "cserafimescu@vcomsolutions.com",
        "customer_id" : "20",
        "vmanager_cc" : "True",
        "vmanager_tp" : "True",
        "customer_name" : "vCom Solutions",
        "is_so" : "0"
    }
]
```

I need to store "customer id", "user_name","user_email" in an array(nsuserdefaults) and pass them to another controller(tableview section )

//Retreived values from NSUserdefaults in tableviewcontroller. Now i need to pass these values in an array and show in 1st section if tableview.

```
//Retreiving Username
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if  let usernameRetrieved = defaults.string(forKey: "userNameKey")
    {
        print("got username in side menu: \(usernameRetrieved)")

    }

    //Retreiving CustomerName
    let defaults1 = UserDefaults.standard
    if let customerNameRetrieved = defaults1.string(forKey: "customerNameKey")
    {
        print("got Customer Name in side menu: \(customerNameRetrieved)")

    }

    //Retreiving User Email Id
    let defaults2 = UserDefaults.standard
    if let emailIDRetrieved = defaults2.string(forKey: "userEmailKey")
    {
        print("got Email Id in side menu: \(emailIDRetrieved)")

    }
```

Comment: This is Dictionary not array.

Comment: yes. i need to save the mentioned values in an array and show them in a section in tableview. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What have you try?

Comment: Im not sure how to retreive specific values from response,store in an array,save it to nsuserdefaults, and use it in a tableview

Comment: Then show the code how you are retrieving this  response also specify the version of your swift.

Answer (score 0):

> Environment : Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0

I had created the same structure as per your requirement.

```
let arrInfo: [Dictionary<String,Any>] =
                  [["Description":"Hello",
                    "Message":"Message",
                    "vmanager_account":"vmanager_account",
                    "user_id" : "174",
                    "login_name" : "ssrikanth",
                    "user_name" : "Surya Srikanth",
                    "owner_id" : "1",
                    "user_email" : "cserafimescu@vcomsolutions.com",
                    "customer_id" : "20",
                    "vmanager_cc" : "True",
                    "vmanager_tp" : "True",
                    "customer_name" : "vCom Solutions",
                    "is_so" : "0"]]
```

Store the Array in `UserDefaults`.

```
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefault.setValue(arrInfo, forKey: "storeArray")
    userDefault.synchronize()
```

Retrieve the Array from `UserDefaults`.

```
    if((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "storeArray")) != nil){
        let getArray = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "storeArray") as! [Dictionary<String,Any>])

        let dict = getArray[0]
        print("Customer ID : ",dict["customer_id"])
    }
```

Hope it works for you!!!

Comment: Actually i saved the details in Logincontroller. I retreieved it in Tableview controller since i need to user 3 values in 1st section on tableview. I need to store the 3 values in an array and show in that section

Comment: You need 3 records for 1st section on tableview from saved details, right.

Comment: "customer_name" : "vCom Solutions",
 "user_name" : "Surya Srikanth",
  "user_email" : "cserafimescu@vcomsolutions.com",
These values , i need to show in 1st section of tableview

I have retreived it from Login Controller already.  Now i have to save it in an array and pass to the section rows

Comment: So you can directly get those value from **dict**. As I had already displayed the Customer ID in my answer.

Comment: Im not sure how to add it to the tableviewsection row

Comment: //Retreiving CustomerName
        let defaults1 = UserDefaults.standard
        if let customerNameRetrieved = defaults1.string(forKey: "customerNameKey")
        {
            print("got Customer Name in side menu: \(customerNameRetrieved)")
            
        }
This is how i retreived it in tableviewcontroller. Suppose i want to show this value in section 1 row. what to do?